# Allow users to edit information, but require admin approval before going live

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a website using Rails 4.4 where users can exhibit their property for sale. Users provide data and pictures of their properties by signing up and uploading it, then an admin verifies the data and asks the user if we can make the data live before approving it and making it live.

I want to allow the user to come back and edit or add new data. For example a user might want to add a new picture or update the address of their property.

How can I enable the user to edit live data without it actually going live?

Should I maintain two separate databases - one for read only and live data, and the other one only for edits (which is an exact replica of live)? Even if I make two databases, how can I update the updated data and add it in the production?

Comment: What if you do it with join table and permissions like in [this post](http://www.jefferydurand.com/ruby/rails/domain/modeling/user/permissions/2016/06/15/user-permissions-through-join-table.html). If I understand correctly, Admin would change some status, nothing more. I suppose it can be done in single DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach this by storing edited fields as a separate schema with an `approve` action that updates the linked property.

This is partially incomplete / pseudocode — you are responsible for your own work:

Models:

```
class PropertyEdit
  belongs_to :property
  belongs_to :reviewer, class_name: 'Admin'
  enum :state, [ :pending, :approved, :cancelled ]

  def approve_changes(admin)
    if property.update { field_name => suggested_value }
      self.reviewer = admin
      approved!
    else
      # Handle error
    end
  end
end

class Property
  has_many :property_edits
end
```

Controller methods for handling the property update:

```
class PropertiesController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    @property = Property.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @property = Property.find(params[:id])
    @property.attributes = property_update_params
    if @property.valid?
      @property.changes.each do |attribute, (old, new)|
        edit = @property.property_edits.new({
          field_name: attribute,
          previous_value: old,
          suggested_value: new
        })

        edit.save
      end

      flash[:success] = "Your updates will be live once approved."
      redirect_to property_path(@property)
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

protected

  def property_update_params
    params.require(:property).permit(:price, :address, :city)
  end
end
```

To handle reviewing edits, you now have a single edit available for approval at a time, and a log of all of the changes.

You will probably want to add logic to handle edge cases and communication:

1. Cancel pending edits when newer ones are entered for the same field
2. Build an instance of Property with pending edits for the user to see; use `_changed?` attributes to show “pending” tags on relevant edits
3. Figure out how to best integrate file handling for photos, since you'll need to determine the best time to handle any transformations, compression, etc

Comment: Hi @coreyward,Thanks for this answer...i appreciate this approach and it looks good but i will need to complete this approach with full end to end implementation creating new table ..however,i do have many tables that user fills up..details,contacts,addresess,pictures,videos...so do i even need to create new existing-tables_edits table to hold new updated data  for each one tooo?????

Comment: @Milind Not at all, just use a [polymorphism](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) on the FooEdit model. This will allow it to store the type and id of the associated model, regardless of what it is (Property, Contact, Picture, etc). Here's the guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Comment: Thanks @coreyward...I will use this approach and add all fields that i need in the polymorphic table..